# Typescript private property declared but not used

Tags: typescript

I have a private property declared in the constructor and also used in the constructor to retrieve some value. I get TS6138: PROPERTY 'xxxx' is declared but never used.

```
constructor(private xxxx: Ixxxx) {
    this.abc = xxxx.get();
}
```

I am upgrading to typescript 2.4.2. 
If I remove private then the error goes away. Obviously the property becomes public which I don't want.

Comment: Change it to `this.abc = this.xxxx.get();`, though if you're indeed not using it in the rest of the class and it's private, then why do you need it as a member?

Comment: You are right it can just be a constructor prameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is correct, you're referencing the constructor argument, not the property. If you want to access the property, you'd have to:

```
constructor(private xxxx: Ixxxx) { // xxxx is constructor arg and private property
    this.abc = this.xxxx.get();
}
```

If you're not planning on using the property anywhere else in your class, you might as well remove the `private` modifier and use the constructor argument instead:

```
constructor(xxxx: Ixxxx) { // xxxx is constructor arg
    this.abc = xxxx.get();
}
```

Doing this will not result in `xxxx` becoming a `public` property. Only adding the `public` keyword will do that:

```
constructor(public xxxx: Ixxxx) { // xxxx is constructor arg and public property
    this.abc = this.xxxx.get();
}
```